# mysql : check date range

Tags: mysql, sql

We have table structure like

```
id | startDay | startMonth | startYear | endDay | endMonth | endYear    
1  | 22       | 12         | 2012      | 25     | 1        | 2013
```

Now we have another date range like startDate,startMonth, startYear i.e. **25|12|2012** and endDay,endMonth,endYear i.e **10|1|2013**. 
I want the query to get the records from table where provided date range is present in table. Means record first in this case.
How to write query for this?

Comment: Why not to use `date` type for date field for your start and end dates? This is what this type is meant for - dealing with dates in `mysql`.

Comment: @Nemoden actually this table structure is already design, so we can not change the structure right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take @**[MarcB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)**['s advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016918/491243). But if you don't have time to alter your table, alternatively, you can also use the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ('2012-12-25' BETWEEN DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', startYear, startMonth, startDay)) AND
                  DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', endYear, endMonth, endDay))) AND
      ('2013-01-10' BETWEEN DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', startYear, startMonth, startDay)) AND
                  DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', endYear, endMonth, endDay)))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f3a2/4)

Answer (score 4):

Ditch this structure, and use native date fields:

```
id start_date  end_date
1  2012-12-22  2013-1-25
```

then you can use native mysql date/time functions and comparisons, e.g.

```
SELECT id WHERE yourdate BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

instead of having to use hideously ugly multi-level comparisons to properly compare such fragmented values:

```
SELECT id where YEAR(yourdate) < startYear OR (YEAR(yourdate) > startYear AND MONTH(yourdate) < startMOnth) etc... etc....etc..
```

Comment: I want to check range not a date between startDate and endDate. I want to check provided startDate and endDate is present in the tables startDate and endDate. how to check this